# AJAX file upload to php, nothing being sent?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input on my website which allows the user to select a file for upload

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

At the end of my page, I have a button which calls a javascript function. This function needs to check if the user has specified a file for upload and if so, upload the file (php) and obtain the filename.

How can I go about accessing the file input form from javascript? i.e. how can I get the 'post' file information to call 'upload_file.php' with.

ps. I'd rather not use JQuery

edit - i've tried this and it doesn't seem to work

```
function uploadFile(){
    var files = document.getElementById('file');
    var file = files.files[0];

    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","uploadfile.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data")
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("thefile", file);
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
```

php:

```
<?php

echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["thefile"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["thefile"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["thefile"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["thefile"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

?>
```

is giving me an alert saying the file name is blank, the type is blank, size is 0 etc...

Comment: Submit? How? An ordinary form submission, or AJAX (using XHR2)?

Comment: oh, sorry. AJAX - the user doesn't leave the page. Also, I think using XHR2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by replacing:

```
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data")
```

with

```
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is accessable through the DOM, just like any other element. The only restriction is you can't alter it for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.simonerodriguez.com/ajax-form-submit-example/

Check this link for ajax post.
You can simply post it like a normal form, need no extra efforts for same.

Answer (score 0):

Have u considered HTML5 File API?

Related StackOverFlow:

[Html 5 File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162102/html-5-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some thing like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/kHQLp/4/

Answer (score 0):

Doing this through AJAX has the following problems can achieved as thus (except for IE).

1) It is impossible for IE. If somebody has found a way give me a shout. What I did is just submit the form in the normal way and return an updated page.

2) For FF (and if memory serves me right Opera and Safari) the following snippet works

```
var fileTag = document.getElementById('id for input element');
var file = fileTag.files[0];

// You can check the type here by checking the string file.type

var data = file.getAsBinary(); // Or getAsText()
```

3) For Chrome use this code

```
var fileTag = document.getElementById('id for input element');
var file = fileTag.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() { /* Use reader.result as it has loaded */  };
reader.onerror = function(e) { /*  and error occurred - handle it */ };
reader.readAsText(file); // I think there is also a function readAsBinary.
```

When you have got the contents of the file you can post it using AJAX