# How to get the directory tree from the client

Tags: file, web, directory, client

I'm trying to make a website where a user can choose a directory from his/her pc. Then i want to get a full directory tree from that point. So that i can process the filenames. It's not necessary to upload anything. Just the filenames are enough.
The closest thing i have seen is the upload procedure on http://www.connect.garmin.com.
When you plug in your gps and click on upload. The site gives you a full list of files that can be uploaded from your gps and whether or not you have already uploaded it.

How can this be done? PHP, javascript or a plugin in python?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there are a few people that had the same question that you did, here is a Link to a blog that I found on another Question on SO
[HTML5 Upload Blog](http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/)

here is the SO Question I found it on
[Html 5 File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162102/html-5-file-upload)

there is a lot of information on that blog that is very useful and I think that you will find everything that you are asking there.

Most of the File Browsing is done by the clients Web Browser so you won't have to worry about coding the actual pop up window. you just have to give the browser the type of files that you are looking for.